# Receiving Notfication when app is running

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-8, notifications, push-notification

In fear of asking a question that might have been asked before, but my search skills did not able me to find. Okay, so here goes.

I have Windows Phone 8 App, where I can receive TileUpdates and Notifications, when My app is not running in the foreground. This I did by following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202940(v=vs.105).aspx

In that link I learned that for getting notifications when app is running I should simply attach an event for the reception case. This I did in my AcquirePushChannel() function, which looks as follows:

```
public static void AcquirePushChannel()
    {
        CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");


        if (CurrentChannel == null)
        {
            CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
            CurrentChannel.Open();
            if (!CurrentChannel.IsShellToastBound)
            {
                CurrentChannel.BindToShellTile();
            }
            CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();
            CurrentChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(Push_NotificationRecieved);

        }
        if (!CurrentChannel.IsShellTileBound)
        {
            CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();
            CurrentChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(Push_NotificationRecieved);
        }

            CurrentChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(Push_NotificationChannelChanged);
    }
```

I have implemented CurrentChannel.ChannelUriUpdated, for the case that channelUri changes and I execute some code to also changes my ChannelsTable in the Cloud.
My Push_NotificationRecieved looks like:

```
private static void Push_NotificationRecieved(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        string relativeUri = string.Empty;

        message.AppendFormat("Received Toast {0}:\n", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

        // Parse out the information that was part of the message.
        foreach (string key in e.Collection.Keys)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", key, e.Collection[key]);

            if (string.Compare(
                key,
                "wp:Param",
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                relativeUri = e.Collection[key];
            }
        }

        // Display a dialog of all the fields in the toast.
        MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());
        //Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((message) => MessageBox.Show(message.ToString()));
    }
```

I cannot see why the notification is not registered. Since in my log in the cloud I receive that the Toast Notification was received?

Any Ideas? Furthermore can I display the toast from the code or something similar, as far as I have read it is not possible?

**Extra**

Have tried changing the functions to public but did not help with the problem.
Anybody have an Idea to why the event is not firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you posted is almost correct. From the previous you have:

```
public static void AcquirePushChannel()
{
    CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");


    if (CurrentChannel == null)
    {
        CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
        CurrentChannel.Open();
        if (!CurrentChannel.IsShellToastBound)
        {
            CurrentChannel.BindToShellTile();
        }
        CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();

    }
    if (!CurrentChannel.IsShellTileBound)
    {
        CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();
    }

        CurrentChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(Push_NotificationChannelChanged);
        CurrentChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += CurrentChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived;
}
```

And to that you have to add:

```
private static void CurrentChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    string relativeUri = string.Empty;

    message.AppendFormat("Received Toast {0}:\n", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

    // Parse out the information that was part of the message.
    foreach (string key in e.Collection.Keys)
    {
        message.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", key, e.Collection[key]);

        if (string.Compare(
            key,
            "wp:Param",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            relativeUri = e.Collection[key];
        }
    }

    // Display a dialog of all the fields in the toast.
    MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());
}
```

So all you send is inside the e.collection. So you can from the server send all kind of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Of course just after I set a bounty to run I got it working. So here is the updated code.

```
public static void AcquirePushChannel()
{
    CurrentChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");


    if (CurrentChannel == null)
    {
        CurrentChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
        CurrentChannel.Open();
        if (!CurrentChannel.IsShellToastBound)
        {
            CurrentChannel.BindToShellTile();
        }
        CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();

    }
    if (!CurrentChannel.IsShellTileBound)
    {
        CurrentChannel.BindToShellToast();
    }

        CurrentChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(Push_NotificationChannelChanged);
        CurrentChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += CurrentChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived;
}
```

Okay so the reason for this, is that you need to set the events on every startup. Then you will get the wished properties. Then you have to create your own code for getting what you want :)